# localizar botão no protractor/angular

Tags: angularjs

Olá!

Já tentei a localização (Protractor) do botão "Novo" dos jeitos abaixo, tem alguma orientação de como fazer?

```
<button class="btn btn-link float-right" data-placement="top" type="button" title="Novo"> <i class="material-icons md-36">add_circle</i> </button>


element(by.xpath('/html/body/ng-component/span/div/main/div/ng-component/cmn-card-page-list-base/cmn-card-page-base/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/cmn-button-new/cmn-card-page-base-button/div/button'));

element(by.cssContainingText('.material-icons.md-36t', 'add_circle'));

element(by.css('.button.btn.btn-link.float-right'));

element(by.css(button[type = 'button']));

element(by.css('.btn.btn-link.float-right'));
```

Agradecida.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Chegou a utilizar o `element(by.className('btn-link'))`, quem sabe pode ser uma solução. Para ver a aplicação é só consultar aqui: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.className

Também pode ser por conta do botão não estão visível na tela ainda, tu pode fazer uma verificação esperando ele ficar clicavel ou visível: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions